# reading Lotus Notes documents via COM

Tags: python, com, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to read e-mails in a Lotus Notes database via python and com. (using pythonwin and win32com)

I can connect to the database and read NotesDocument items but

```
doc = folder.GetFirstDocument()
doc.GetItemValue('Body')
```

returns the plain text contents of the email. I can get the headers, subject, date, etc but body is plaintext. I'm trying to fetch the HTML source of the email which includes links and other formatting. I know the stuff is there because within Notes I can view-->show--> page source.

I've tried

```
doc.GetMIMEEntity('Body')
```

but this returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line right after where you get the session:

```
session.ConvertMIME = False
```

**Update:**

Barry commented that it worked this way:

```
doc.GetFirstItem("Body").GetMIMEEntity()
```

Comment: ok - now Body is just blank, `u''`. Other values like subject and headers are still coming through.

Comment: That's because the type of the Body item can be either Note Rich Text or MIME.  When you turn off conversion, you need to test the type and then either use the classes/methods associated with NotesRichTextItem, or the clases associated with NotesMimeEntity.

Comment: With convertMIME turned off, do bodyItem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body") and then check bodyItem.Type().  There's a list of values here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098986 Note that you cannot count on an item being the expected type. Notes is schema-less. The Body will almost always be Rich Text or MIME, but if you are dealing with unknown data sources it could be anything.  Specifically, I've seen plain Text (1280) and HTML (21) on rare occasions. Much depends on what software actually created the message. Theoretically, it could be anything.

Comment: Thanks! I had to bodyItem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body") followed by mime= bodyItem.GetMIMEEntity(). Then I was able to do things like mime.ContentAsText to read and parse the html content.

Comment: Great! I thought doc.GetMIMEEntity('Body') would have done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The body is a rich text item.  You won't be able to access the HTML version of the body field, but you can navigate around the rich text item using the NotesRichText... classes.

The [NotesRichTextNavigator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_NOTESRICHTEXTNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html) class has an example to get you started.  It is unfortunately not very easy to get around in that object.

Comment: interesting - I can't create a navigator object. `doc.GetFirstItem('Body').CreateNavigator()` raises an exception, no such attribute CreateNavigator.

Comment: Any idea why the body item would not behave like a rich text item? It doesn't seem to have GetFormattedText() or a host of other functions / attributes in the documentation.

Comment: its been a long time since I used python COM to call lotus notes backend classes... but, is python implicitly converting your item to string, giving CreateNavigator() no context...? I might try to convert it to mime and try get a mime entity, to see if you get an object back that way.

Comment: I'd avoid chaining methods.  Do bodyItem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body"), then operate on bodyItem. See my comments on Panu's answer.  Note that there's even an obscure case where the Body item literally disappears. I.e., you check doc.hasItem("Body") -- which you should always do! -- and it's there, but when you do doc.getFirstItem("Body") it's cgone.  That can happen when convertMIME=true (whihc is the default) and the message is multi-part MIME with no content.  I have an old blog post about that case here: http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/d6plinks/RSCZ-7S34GL